# Is there any method to extract charts from excel using NPOI?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, npoi

Is there any method to extract charts from excel using NPOI, or to extract the XML code and parse it into a word document ? I don't find any support to extract the xml or the chart, i need the chart object the solution with image don't work, i can't use the microsoft office interop. Or is there any free lib that can do this ?

Comment: what did you try till now? Did you try workbook.GetAllPictures()?

Comment: @KrishnaChaithanyaMuthyala i want the object or the xml code for that chart not the image, if i get the image i can't modify any data. I try to extract the xml by unzip the excel file, but this method did not work.